# Halo reach stats api?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

Can someone please give me an example of how to access the [Halo: Reach stats API](http://www.bungie.net/fanclub/statsapi/Group/Resources/Article.aspx?cid=545064)

using jquery ajax?

Here is an exert:

> GetGameHistory(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
>
> This function is used to browse through a player's history of games.
>
> Parameters
>
> identifier: Your application's identifier string.
>   gamertag: The target player's gamertag.
>   variant_class: The variant class of game to get. Valid values are "Campaign", > "Firefight", "Competitive", "Arena", "Invasion", "Custom". Pass "Unknown" to get all games.
>   iPage: The page of results you want, starting at page 0.
>
> Return Value
>   A GameHistoryResponse object containing a list of the games matching the criteria you specified.
>
> Example
>   http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc /player/gamehistory/ {identifier}/{gamertag}/{variant_class_string}/{iPage}

here was my attempt:

```
var apikey      = 'xxx';
var gamertag    = 'The Hailwood';
var variant     = 'Competitive';
var page        = '0';
var url = 'http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/player/gamehistory/'+apikey+'/'+gamertag+'/'+variant+'/'+page;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#return').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

However I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/player/gamehistory/xxx/The%20Hailwood/Competitive/0. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

What does this mean?

---

**Update:**
Ok so I fixed it by setting appropriate permissions.

But now I am getting a 400 response from the server.

Any idea what would cause this?

---

**Update2:**
**API IS NOT OPERATIONAL!** hence why it is not working :(

Comment: The API is now operational.  You will have to regenerate your API key and sign up for a Bungie Pro account and your requests will start working.  If you ever need a C# wrapper around the services, check out http://haloreachapi.codeplex.com.

Comment: Cheers,

Its php for me but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you cant access it from a localhost url, try putting it on your server/hosting and giving it a test there. It should then work

Comment: This is actually run in a google chrome extension, so the error is `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/player/gamehistory/xxx/The%20Hailwood/Competitive/0. Origin chrome-extension://melchgapfmhmlefkbddmhajikciefnni is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: I would expect this is because you are requesting the data from the extension and not from a true url. I dont know anything about chrome-ext's though.

Comment: Yeah i fixed it. I had to give the extension permission to that domain.

But please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what you do. As of now the API service is down.

Answer (score 0):

400 is just a generic bad request, but it's client range which means the server *believes* (may be lying, may be wrong) that *something* is wrong with your request - but it could be literally anything so it's up to the server to provide additional detail with the response to help you.